# May two or more bases of different sizes generate a same topology?

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering the following example of the standard real topology:

all open intervals with rational endpoints are a base for the standard real topology, as are the open intervals with irrational endpoints; however, these two bases are completely disjoint. The question is if two bases or more of different sizes could generate the same topology?

Besides, I would like to extend the scale of the question: regarding the comparison of topology, we have the following lemma from James Munkres' Topology:

let $B$ and $B'$ be bases for the topologies $T$ and $T'$, respectively, on the set $X$, then the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is finer than $T'$;
2. for each $x \in X$ and each basis element $b \in B$ containing $x$, there is a basis element $b' \in B'$ such that $x \in b' \subseteq b$

Here is my extended part of the question for the above lemma:

Let $T$ and $T'$ be two topologies on a set $X$, and the sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ be the bases of $T$, the sets $B_1'$ and $B_2'$ be the bases of $T'$. If so, how to check if $T$ is finer than $T$ by using the above lemma since $T$ and $T'$ could be generated by two bases of different sizes?

I could take one counter example for reference:

Suppose the set $B = \{ \emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{b\}\}$ is a base for the topology $T = \{X,\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{b\}\}$ on the set $X=\{a,b,c\}$,

the set $B'_1= \{ \emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{c,a\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ and the set $B_2'=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{c\},\{b\}\}$ are the bases for the topology 
$T'=\{X,\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{c,a\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$

$T'$ is obviously finer than $T$; however, it can not be concluded from the comparison of the bases $B$ & $B_2'$ by using the lemma, because there doesn't exist the relation of containing between $B$ and $B_2'$. At this point, can we say the lemma fails?

Comment: You correctly answered the question in your second paragraph yourself. If you are worried about disjoint, you could make the second all intervals of the real line, rational or irrational, and they are not disjoint.

Comment: thank you, I think it's right, I just can't make sure when there is no explicit statement in the book.

Answer (score 2):

The lemma is correct, and it does cover the case of your $B$ and $B2$.  For each point $x$ in your space (i.e., $a$ or $b$ or $c$) and each set from $B$ that contains $x$, there is a subset that is in $B2$ and also contains $x$ (namely $\{x\}$).  Note that the lemma is not about "the relation of containing between $B$ and $B2$" but rather about containments between elements of $B2$ and elements of $B$.

As for your first question, "if two bases or more of different size could generate the same topology", you've already proved an affirmative answer by exhibiting some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What if comparing B with B1? you see there is a element {c,a} in B1 which can not match the requirement of the lemma, and it is not the subset of any element of B.

Comment: @Lin You probably meant $B1'$ when you wrote $B1$, as there is no $B1$ in your question.  The lemma works with $B$ and $B1'$: For each point $x$ in your space (i.e., $a$ or $b$ or $c$) and each set from $B$ that contains $x$, there is a subset that is in $B1'$ and also contains $x$ (namely $\{x\}$). It is true that $B1'$ also has some elements, like $\{a,c\}$ that are not needed for this verification, but that makes no difference. Once $B1'$ has enough elements to satisfy the criterion in the lemma, having some extra elements does no harm.

Comment: Yes, I did mean B1' at first. and Thank you for your explanation.